# Как обработать исключение + как проверить входные данные на принадлежность к определенному типу?

Tags: java, исключения

Всем привет! я ввожу целое число с клавиатуры и хочу сделать так чтобы при вводе некорректного значения программа отработала нормально,т.е. просила ввести число еще раз, либо просто завершалась нормально без стэктрэйса. При вводе любого значения отличного от int появляется исключения типа java.util.InputMismatchException. Мой код -

```
public static int size() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        if (n>0 && n<11)
            return n;
        else
            System.out.println("Введите корректное значение!");
            return 0;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = size();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int size() {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10: ");
  while (true) {
    try {
      int n = scanner.nextInt();
      if (n > 0 && n < 11)
        return n;
      else
        System.out.println("Введите корректное значение!");
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Введите корректное значение!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В том то и проблема что компилятор ругается на "return 0"

Comment: "компилятор ругается" - ?

Comment: unreachable statement получаю

Comment: @Жаважуниор, На какие еще `return 0`? Там нет 0 и быть не может. Условие стоит на больше нуля. Это у вас стоит 0 и вообще неправильно сделано и отлова ошибок нет. По этому и ругается.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int size() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10: ");
    while (true) {
        String n = scanner.nextLine();
        if (n.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") && Integer.parseInt(n) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(n) < 11) {
            return Integer.parseInt(n);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введите корректное значение!");
        }
    }
}
```

Это будет крутиться пока заданное число не будет в нужном диапазоне.
Переделанный вариант.

Comment: Напишите строку.

Comment: Да, сразу не сообразил. Переделал. Выглядит страшно не красиво, но работает.

Comment: Зачем такие сложности...Достаточно просто отследить, через `try-catch` и все. Как сделал @Igor.

Comment: Согласен. Но в случае исключения, программа завершится, а я хотел предложить вариант с возможностью продолжить выполнение программы.

Comment: С каких таких, стало завершать при перехвате? Вы что-то путаете с фатальными крашингами программы, когда исключение не обработано.

Comment: Там в варианте от @Igor нужно в catch добавить scanner.nextLine();